# Four term exact sequence for Artin algebras

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Suppose $\Lambda$ is an Artin algebra, i.e. an algebra finitely generated as $R$-module for a commutative Artin ring $R$, $A$ is a finitely generated left $\Lambda$-module, and $X$ a finitely generated left $\Lambda^{op}$-module. Then there should be a short exact sequence

$$
0 \to Ext^1_{\Lambda^{op}}(Tr A,X) \to X \otimes_{\Lambda} A \to Hom_{\Lambda^{op}}(A^*,X) \to Ext^2_{\Lambda^{op}}(Tr A,X) \to 0
$$

where $Tr$ denotes the transpose of a module, and $(-)^*$ denotes the duality $Hom_{\Lambda}(-,\Lambda)$. Could anyone give me a proof of this? It is Proposition $3.2$ in `Representation theory of Artin algebras', but I do not understand the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that may be helpful for the last part of your sequence.  Lemma 2.12 of *Elements of the representation theory of associative algebras I* by Assem Simson Skowronski  can be adapted to give you an exact sequence 
$$ X \otimes _\Lambda A \to \hom_\Lambda(A^t, X) \to \operatorname{sthom}_\Lambda (A^t, X) \to 0 $$
sthom denotes homomorphisms in the stable category; since there is an exact sequence
$$ 0 \to A^t \to P_0^t \to P_1^t \to \operatorname{Tr}A \to 0 $$ with the inner terms projective, the stable hom space can be identified with $\operatorname{Ext}^2_\Lambda(\operatorname{Tr} A, X)$ by dimension-shifting.